# Porting Movino on symbian

Tags: symbian

H all,

I have downloaded the movino for symbian from http://movino.org

But, i 've been facing may build error while building the app for symbian 3rd edition.

Is anyone successfully done this?

Or 
Any suggestions  on this?

Thanks,
KB

Comment: it's a shame symbian releases have never been reverse compatible. Even though Win mobile is inferior in a lot of ways, at least it still runs my code which was created for when it was still 'pocketpc'

Comment: Have you looked at the compiling instructions here: http://movino.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/movino/movino-symbian/trunk/COMPILING?view=markup
They mention S60 3rd Ed, so presumably it can be built. There are some specific steps required to build or download the dependent libraries.

Comment: Since the app seems already be available for Symbian, this question is more about compiling rather than porting it. If you need help compiling the code, please be more specific about the problems you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

What about the Java ME version of Movino?